# Cannot open static file if my IP is local

Tags: iis

I run IIS on Windows 2008 R2 Standart Edition & bind IIS on a public IP. At my desktop PC, I cannot open any non-asp files if my IP is local -ie 192.168.35.45-

I **can** open

- http://mysite.com/test.**asp**

I **cannot** open

- http://mysite.com/test.css  (same file, renamed)
- http://mysite.com/test.txt  (same file, renamed)
- http://mysite.com/a-test-image.jpg

I can open all these files if I use **ktunnel**/proxy

I can open all these files if I use **real IP** in TCP/IP settings on my desktop

As you guess all links are accessible from the internet

Comment: Is this just on your computer?  Does it only happen for a particular web browser?  If your browser is IE have you done anything weird with security zones?

Comment: Any computer which have local IP. Tested with IE & Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one website set up in IIS manager pointing at the same folder... each having different settings?

Comment: I use same folder for mysite.com & www.mysite.com & mysite.org & www.mysite.org. All of them listed as mysite.com in the sites tree-list.

Comment: OK, then time to add more detail on what happens when you try to open the file. If you can add the 'Tracing' Role Service, and enable Failed Request Tracing for the site, then configure a rule to trace all content, you may be able to work out what module is preventing your access. Could be that the static file handler mapping works differently remotely because of something else configured; IIS doesn't usually behave this way, so it's additional complexity that's killing ya.

Comment: Chrome says: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) I can't trace because there is no server response/code

Comment: What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: I have no idea; it looks like the static module disabled for local access/IP for all sites.

Comment: if you're prepared to share your applicationhost.config (strip out any encrypted properties - they start with [enc: ) then we can take a look, but it sounds like there's something complicated about the setup that you're not telling us. Perhaps there's URL rewriting, or URL filtering, or other features that haven't been mentioned...